# jquery checkbox filtered search not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am not expert in coding, I have been trying to fix this for hours now.
But no luck tried everything, nee help from experts.

The following script has 4 functions.

1. page number
2. send data from text input field.
3. send data from select2 dropdown option.
4. send data from simple checkbox.

The last checkbox is not working, why ?

```
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    load_data(1);

    function load_data(page,query,city,category)
    {  
      
      $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_data.html",
        method:"POST",
        data:{page:page, query:query, city:city, category:category},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(){
      var page = $(this).data('page_number');
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      var city = $('#multiple').val();
      var category = $('#category').val();
      load_data(page, query, city, category);
    });

$('#search_box').keyup(function () {
    var query = $('#search_box').val();
    var city = $('#multiple').val();
    var category = $('#category').val();
    load_data(1, query, city, category);
});
$('#multiple').change(function () {
    var query = $('#search_box').val();
    var city = $('#multiple').val();
    var category = $('#category').val();
    load_data(1, query, city, category);
});
$('#category').change(function () {
    var query = $('#search_box').val();
    var city = $('#multiple').val();
    var category = $('#category').val();
    load_data(1, query, city, category);
});
$(function() {
  $("#multiple").select2({
    closeOnSelect : false,
    placeholder : "Search City",
    allowHtml: true,
    allowClear: true,
    tags: true
  });
});



function iformat(icon, badge,) {
  var originalOption = icon.element;
  var originalOptionBadge = $(originalOption).data('badge');

  return $('<span><i class="fa ' + $(originalOption).data('icon') + '"></i> ' +   icon.text + '<span class="badge">' + originalOptionBadge + '</span></span>');
}

    
  });
</script>
```

here is the checkbox code

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="category" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="category" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
  <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="category" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
  <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because they all have the same id, if you want to get the values of those which are checked your want something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(":input[id^='category']:checked").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="category" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="category" name="vehicle2" value="Car" checked>
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="category" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" checked>
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
```

Your probably have to pass it as an array nested item in a json object to your ajax call, I hope this helps